# How to set up wp multisite?

Tags: multisite, errors, 404-error

After installing falling all the steps (http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) I tried to create sites.

I can't access the dashboard of any site created. It says page not found (error 404).
To start fresh I uninstalled WP and then Installed following every step.
I have no clue what to do.
I can only access the dashboard of the root site. All the rest I can't.

Comment: Any explicit error messages? Any [debugging info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your network sites allowed to install in subdomain  like  abc.hgd.com  then you need to setup the Wild card DNS setting.

I think that could be creating the problem for you and redirecting you to the 404 error page.

Can you please let me know thw steps you followed to setup your multisite network?

It will help me to diagnose and get you a solution for this.

And for reference in installing an multisite network you can check this tutorial:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwGC-_KH0jY&list=TL-0rX5lBuOXgsDct31TCGFvM8PebAUUeD

http://wpmu.org/wordpress-multisite-guide/

Let me know if it resolves your problem.